# navigate or jump between laravel error logs with less command?

Tags: less

I use less command to navigate laravel error log files, I usually do it like this:

```
less laravel.log
```

and then

```
Shift + Alt + G
```

to navigate using up and down keys, the thing is this is not very handy since laravel errors are lots of text... I'd like to know if there's a way to jump between errors, or maybe filter them.

Taking into account that each laravel error starts with a timstamp like this:

```
[2023-06-29 21:07:05]
```

Thanks in advance